# kill -INT pid can not kill process inside ksh script

Tags: signals, ksh, sigint

Two scenarios:

1. running commands in CLI

   ## zfs send rpool/fs@snap | zfs recv rpool/fs1@snap &

   [1] 139781

   ## ps -ef|grep zfs

   ```
       root 139783 119679   0 23:28:34 kz/term/2    0:00 grep zfs
       root 139781 119679   3 23:28:30 kz/term/2    0:02 zfs recv rpool/fs1@snap
       root 139780 119679   3 23:28:30 kz/term/2    0:03 zfs send rpool/fs@snap
   ```

   ## kill -INT 139780

   ## ps -ef|grep zfs

   ```
       root 139781 119679   7 23:28:30 kz/term/2    0:08 zfs recv rpool/fs1@snap
       root 139785 119679   0 23:28:42 kz/term/2    0:00 grep zfs
   ```

We can see that the current shell(119679) create two
children(139780&139781), and kill -INT can interrupt
139780 successfully.

1. Now we wrote a ksh script to do the almost same work

   ## cat a.sh

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ksh -p
   echo $$
   zfs send rpool/fs@snap | zfs recv rpool/fs1@snap &
   pid=$(ps -ef|grep 'zfs send rpool/fs@snap'|grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
   /usr/bin/kill -s INT $pid
   sleep 1
   ps -ef|grep zfs
   ```

   ## ./a.sh

   ```
   139788
       root 139791 139789   1 23:30:57 kz/term/2    0:01 zfs send rpool/fs@snap
       root 139789 139788   1 23:30:57 kz/term/2    0:01 zfs recv rpool/fs1@snap
       root 139798 139788   0 23:30:58 kz/term/2    0:00 grep zfs
   ```

Now a.sh forked 139789, and 139789 forked 139791, and in this situation, 
a.sh called kill command to send the SIGINT to 139791, but it failed.

Why not a.sh forks the 'zfs send' process? (in bash script, a.sh forked both send and receive processes)?
Why kill -s INT failed to interrupt the 'zfs send' process?
How to interrupt the send process inside ksh script?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have a nested fork is because you're using the '&' - backgrounding the piped process, meaning the first command in the pipe forks the second, not the shell process. Unfortunately I don't currently have zfs to play with, so I can't check how zfs plays within a process group, but nested forking is the default behaviour for piped backgrounded processes.

**SIGINT** won't work on your parent process because a POSIX compliant parent process will wait only for **SIGCHLD** before terminating itself, ignoring **SIGINT** and **SIGQUIT**.

If you use **SIGTERM** instead :

```
/usr/bin/kill -s TERM $pid
```

your process will handle the signal, and terminate gracefully. 
In the absense of 'zfs', I simulated your piped processes with 'tail':

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh -p
echo $$
#zfs send rpool/fs@snap | zfs recv rpool/fs1@snap &
tail -f foo | tail -f &
#pid=$(ps -ef|grep 'zfs send rpool/fs@snap'|grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
pid=$(ps -ef|grep "t[a]il"| awk '{print $2}')
#/usr/bin/kill -s INT $pid
/usr/bin/kill -s TERM $pid
echo $?
sleep 1
ps -ef|grep "t[a]il"
```

Hope that helps.